# This component requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute

Tags: java, android, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

My app theme extends from AppCompat but I want to use Chip dynamically but when I added Chips dynamically app crashing with exception

```
This component requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute. Update your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

but when I extend app theme to Material app doesn't crash and filter chips works fine but my problem is I dont want to extend theme from Material because it effects my app UI, how can I use chip in this scenario?

Edit:
used bridge, it saves from crashing but when I click chip it does not change appearance of chip that I was clicked

```
Chip chip = new Chip(getContext());
        ChipDrawable chipDrawable = ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(getContext(), null, 0, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Filter);
        chip.setChipDrawable(chipDrawable);
        chip.setCheckable(true);
        chip.setText(itemArrayList.get(i).getName());
        binding.rvReport.addView(chip);
```

Thanks

Comment: Chip(parent.context, null, R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents )

Comment: doesnt work application crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [official documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme):

> Your app theme should inherit from a **Material Components theme**.
>   If you **can't change** your theme, you can do one of the following:
>
> - Inherit from one of our Material Components [**Bridge themes**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes)
> - Continue to inherit from an [**AppCompat theme**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#app-compat-themes) and add some new theme attributes to your theme.

For the Chip you can also define the layout as follows:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
    .../>
```

and then use this code:

```java
Chip chip =
      (Chip) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_chip_layout, chipGroup, false);
//...
chipGroup.addView(chip);
```

Comment: I tried both of these but It also saves from crashing but chip filter is not working as expected in this case. i.e when I click chip it has no effect, no drawable changes, see edited question

Comment: should I include chip drawable? as my application is crashing if I'm creating chip object like you mentioned

Comment: Filter chips created using constructor somehow does not work as expected with Bridge themes(does not hit onCheckedChangedListener). You need to inflate it using xml file. Only that way you can catch check changes. However, I still don't know why it works in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a theme just for that particular Chip which inherits from `Theme.MaterialComponents`, whilst not having to modify your app-wide AppCompat theme:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"/>
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to create dynamic chips

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"   (add theme)
 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"  (add style)
 app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp"  (clear around chip padding)
 ...
/>
```

then

```
//create chip
val chip = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chip_layout, chipGroup, false) as Chip
//add chip
chipGroup.addView(chip )
```